# Exclude points from plotting by color definition?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a 3D scatter plot and color-code the symbols. If the RGB colors are defined by `nan`, why does are the points plotted in black? This expression is okay:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

carr = np.array([[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]]) # RGBA color array

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
h = ax.scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],
               c=carr)
plt.draw()
```

New color array with nan:

```
carr = np.array([[0,0,0,1],np.repeat(np.nan,4),[0,1,0,1]])

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
h = ax.scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],
               c=carr)
plt.draw()
```

The point for which the color is defined as `nan` is shown in black rather than nothing or some other color. Is there a way to make it not show up? In R, points for which colors are defined as `NA` are not plotted, which is convenient when you designate the color by some logical expression.

Of course... I can always subset the array for plotting, but if I can exclude it with the color definition that would be better.

On a side note, why does

```
carr[1:] = np.nan
```

after the first definition of `carr` give me

```
array([[                   0,                    0,                    0,
                           1],
       [-9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808,
        -9223372036854775808],
       [                   0,                    1,                    0,
                           1]])
```

instead of

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,   1.]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with 3D plotting, the same issue exists for `matplotlib.scatter` as well. There are really two issues. The first is that the **different `carr`'s have different internal types**. Note that this will fail:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# This fails since carr[0,0] is of type numpy.int64
carr = np.array([[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]]) # RGBA color array
carr[1] = np.repeat(np.nan,4)

pts = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[2,2]]).T
plt.scatter(pts[0],pts[1],c=carr,s=500)
```

In the next case, if we force `carr` to be a `numpy.float` we can plot, but as noted `nan`'s are shown as black dots:

```
# This works but still puts a black dot for the nan point
carr = np.array([[0.0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]]) # RGBA color array
carr[1] = np.repeat(np.nan,4)

pts = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[2,2]]).T
plt.scatter(pts[0],pts[1],c=carr,s=500)
```

If we instead define a mask, we can index the points we want. This is the preferred method when dealing with numpy arrays:

```
carr = np.array([[0.0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]]) # RGBA color array
carr[1] = np.repeat(np.nan,4)
pts = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[2,2]]).T

idx = ~np.isnan(carr[:,0])
plt.scatter(pts[0][idx],pts[1][idx],c=carr[idx],s=500)
```

Showing the two cases side by side:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I guess I could also add the argument `dtype=np.float` instead also. I forgot this part about Python. The explicit indexing is the most straightforward answer but I was hoping for a clever trick around it that uses the color definition. Oh well.

Comment: @crippledlambda In addition you can always cast an existing array as `A.astype(np.float)`. IMHO this is better than a pyplot solution as you are documenting in the code which indices are being used. If you really wanted you could always wrap `scatter` to apply the filter as shown above, that way you get the effect you want.